# AlertManager logs "open alertmanager.yml: no such file or directory" and fails to start

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

When I docker pull a particular version of AlertManager (**0.21**) and 'docker' run it individually, it works.
However, when I run it inside of a docker compose, the alert manager refuses to start and gives the following error continuously.

```
open alertmanager.yml: no such file or directory
```

When an older version of alert manager (**0.15**) is run with the same configuration in docker compose, it works.

The documentation does not provide a clue.

Note : *Self posting the answer for community as it can take quite a while to figure out what exactly is wrong since not every user (like me) is a advanced user.*

Answer (score 1):

Answer : Explicitly mention the path of alertmanager.yml (--config.file) in the docker compose configuration. This was **not** the case with previous version of alertmanager.

```
alertmanager:    
    restart: always
    command: '--storage.path=/alertmanager --config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml --log.level=debug --cluster.listen-address=""'
    deploy:
     mode: replicated
     replicas: 1
     placement:
      constraints:
        - 'node.labels.role!=replica'
    networks:
        topology-network:
```